# UI testing firstMatch

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

Is it safe to replace all instances in my UI testing code of `.element(boundBy: 0)` with `.firstMatch`?

I would think so, but the documentation from Apple isn't very clear about it (especially in the case of multiple matches even though I only care about the first one).
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementtypequeryprovider/2902250-firstmatch

Comment: Hmm good question. Off the top of my head I don't see why not.

Comment: I swapped it out and it's looking good so far.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of swapping `element(boundBy: 0)` with `firstMatch`, you should chain them.

```
XCUIApplication().cells.element(boundBy:0).firstMatch
```

This will make the query resolve faster if there is more than one cell on-screen. Without `firstMatch`, the test will first get a list of all the cells and then use the first one. With `firstMatch`, the test will look for cells and use the first one it finds.

> Only use firstMatch in cases where you know categorically that a single element will match a query.

You should still do `element(boundBy:)` anywhere where there could plausibly be more than 1 element matching the query, to ensure that when you use `firstMatch`, there is only one element that can match that query. In the situation where there are 3 cells and you want to use the first one, you should still use `element(boundBy: 0)`. If you *know* you only have 1 cell on screen then it's fine to skip `element(boundBy: 0)` and use `firstMatch` instead of `element` to resolve the query faster.

```
// fine if there is only one cell
XCUIApplication().cells.element // also checks for multiple matches
// also fine if there is only one cell
XCUIApplication().cells.firstMatch // does not check for multiple matches
```

Comment: But what would be the problem of using firstMatch without element(boundBy: 0)? It seems to work right now.

Comment: You are guarding against something that Apple calls 'surprising' results in their WWDC talk introducing this API. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/409/ From what I understand, it will probably work without problems when the app is correct but when something goes wrong such that your element isn't found, `firstMatch` handles failure much less gracefully than other APIs.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Already too many 'surprising' results in UI testing as it is.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just ran into a situation where `.element(boundBy: 0)`  exists, but `.firstMatch` doesn't, so I think there's more to the story...